# Github Action workflow_run only on push to main branch

Tags: github-actions

I have a CI workflow that runs on PR and PUSH to main branch.

```
---
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
```

I have another workflow I'd like to only run after CI is complete and conclusion is success but only when it's pushed to main branch.

```
---
name: Build

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI"]
    types:
      - completed
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
```

It runs on both PR and push to main.  How do I get the Build workflow to only run on push to main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can just filter on the branch in the Build workflow (see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#limiting-your-workflow-to-run-based-on-branches):

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI"]
    types:
      - completed
    branches:
      - main
```

Comment: I just tried that and looks like it's still building on PR after CI